# C# get directories ordered by name starting from X

Tags: c#, linq, directory

I need to get the directories within another directory but only those that are "after" X ordering them by dir name.

Example:

```
-Root
  |--DirectoryA
  |--DirectoryB
  |--DirectoryC
  |--DirectoryD
```

So basically something like this:

```
foreach(string path in Directory.GetDirectories("/root/"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(path);
}
```

Output:

```
/root/DirectoryA
/root/DirectoryB
/root/DirectoryC
/root/DirectoryD
```

But I actually need to get only those after C (including it), I guess with Linq it shouldn't be too hard, but I really can't see how.

Maybe something like:

```
Directory.GetDirectories("/root/").OrderByDescending(dirName => 
Path.GetDirectoryName(dirName)) ??
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`SkipWhile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549075(v=vs.110).aspx), assuming the order is alphabetical:

```
foreach(string path in Directory.GetDirectories("/root/")
                                .Select(dir => Path.GetFileName(dir))
                                .SkipWhile(dir => string.Compare(dir, "DirectoryC") < 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine(path);
}
```

This way you will avoid redundant filtering will after encountering the first valid directory.

If you would want to take only the folders before `DirectoryC` you could use [`TakeWhile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534804(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
foreach(string path in Directory.GetDirectories("/root/")
                                .Select(dir => Path.GetFileName(dir))
                                .TakeWhile(dir => string.Compare(dir, "DirectoryC") < 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine(path);
}
```

*Note that [`string.Compare`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/84787k22(v=vs.110).aspx) is culture dependent and you may use [other overloads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hyxc48dt(v=vs.110).aspx) to customize its behavior.*

Comment: I'm getting Error: Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'string'.

Comment: Yeah, you should use `string.Compare`

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Where` extension method

```
foreach(string path in Directory
           .GetDirectories("/root/")
           .Where(d => String.Compare(Path.GetFileName(d), "DirectoryC") > 0))
{
    Console.WriteLine(path);
}
```

You can also include a ordering if you need it, but it will not influence the filtering with `Where`. If you do, append it after `Where` for efficiency.

Comment: Getting the following error: `foreach (string versionDirectory in Directory.GetDirectories("/root/").Where(d => d.Name >= ""))`: CS1061 'string' does not contain a definition for 'Name' and no extension method 'Name' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Comment: With the change you made, I get: Error: Operator '>=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'string'.

Comment: Ok, I thougt it would return a `DirectoryInfo`; however, it returns a string array of of full names (including paths).

Answer (score 0):

or just in case that you are using an older version of .NET you can always write the logic yourself:

```
var directories = Directory.GetDirectories("C:\\").OrderByDescending(r => r).ToArray();
            if (directories != null && directories.Length > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0, Cindex=-1; i < directories.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (Cindex > 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(directories[i]);
                        continue;
                    }
                    if (directories[i] == "DirectoryC")
                    {
                        Cindex = i;
                    }
                }
            }
```